# Python dict key delete if pattern match with other dict key

Tags: python, design-patterns, dictionary, key

Python dict key delete, if key pattern match with other dict key.

e.g.

```
a={'a.b.c.test':1,  'b.x.d.pqr':2,  'c.e.f.dummy':3,  'd.x.y.temp':4}

b={'a.b.c':1,  'b.p.q':20}
```

result

```
a={'b.x.d.pqr':2,'c.e.f.dummy':3,'d.x.y.temp':4}`
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "pattern match"? And on a more general note, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I like to delete the keys from dict a comparing with dict b. But, keys of dict a and dict b are not identical, so comparison will not work. So, I need to match pattern from keys of dict b with dict a and if key pattern matches then only delete the keys from dict a. As a result, I will have dict a shown in above example.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by "match pattern", "key pattern matches", etc. We get that comparing with `==` isn't sufficient, but what do you need to do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "pattern match with other dict key" means "starts with any key in the other dict", the most direct way to write that would be like this:

```
a = {k:v for (k, v) in a.items() if any(k.startswith(k2) for k2 in b)}
```

If that's hard to follow at first glance, it's basically the equivalent of this:

```
def matches(key1, d2):
    for key2 in d2:
        if key1.startswith(key2):
            return True
    return False

c = {}
for key in a:
  if not matches(key, b):
    c[key] = a[key]
a = c
```

This is going to be slower than necessary. If `a` has N keys, and `b` has M keys, the time taken is O(NM). While you can checked "does key `k` exist in dict `b`" in constant time, there's no way to check "does any key starting with `k` exist in dict `b`" without iterating over the whole dict. So, if `b` is potentially large, you probably want to search `sorted(b.keys())` and write a binary search, which will get the time down to O(N log M). But if this isn't a bottleneck, you may be better off sticking with the simple version, just because it's simple.

Note that I'm generating a new `a` with the matches filtered out, rather than deleting the matches. This is almost always a better solution than deleting in-place, for multiple reasons:
 * It's much easier to reason about. Treating objects as immutable and doing pure operations on them means you don't need to think about how states change over time. For example, the naive way to delete in place would run into the problem that you're changing the dictionary while iterating over it, which will raise an exception. Issues like that never come up without mutable operations.
 * It's easier to read, and (once you get the hang of it) even to write.
 * It's almost always faster. (One reason is that it takes a lot more memory allocations and deallocations to repeatedly modify a dictionary than to build one with a comprehension.)

The one tradeoff is memory usage. The delete-in-place implementation has to make a copy of all of the keys; the built-a-new-dict implementation has to have both the filtered dict and the original dict in memory. If you're keeping 99% of the values, and the values are much larger than the keys, this could hurt you. (On the other hand, if you're keeping 10% of the values, and the values are about the same size as the keys, you'll actually *save* space.) That's why it's "almost always" a better solution, rather than "always".

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in list(a.keys()):
    if any(key.startswith(k) for k in b):
       del a[key]
```

Replace `key.startswith(k)` with an appropriate condition for "matching".

Comment: You can't delete from a dictionary while iterating over it. You can iterate over a copy, e.g., `list(a.keys())`, and delete from `a`, but that's generally a bad idea. Filtering a `dict` is almost always better done by generating a new `dict` with only the values you want. It may or may not use more space (you need a copy of all keys and value that pass the filter, instead of a copy of all keys), but it's faster, and simpler, and easier to reason about.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. @abarnert is 100% right. Fixed, somewhat. I went with deleting because that's what the OP asked for, although maybe creating a new dict would be OK as well.

Comment: I'd still add a comment explaining that deleting is very probably not what the OP really wants, even though it s possible. Many people do this because they think it'll be more efficient, or simpler, but they're wrong on both counts.

Comment: @abarnert I personally think your comment is enough, but you can by all means edit my post :) Or explain everything in your answer, which I already upvoted as the most thorough.

Answer (score 0):

```
c={} #result in dict c
for key in b.keys():
    if all([z.count(key)==0 for z in a.keys()]): #string of the key in b should not be substring for any of the keys in a
       c[key]=b[key]
```